# how to display data with where clause while page has loaded

Tags: php, jquery

I want to make a function for displaying database data without refreshing the page. I've tried to verify my php code by filling with a value and it works. But, when I try to call it with jquery the data is not displaying.

This my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var data = $(this).serialize();
  
        $.ajax({
   data: data,
            type: "Post",
            url: "../php/bkk_1/bkk_show.php",
            success: function(data){
  var list = JSON.parse(data);
  for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
 $('#tanggal2').text((list[i]['nama']));
 
    
  }
  return false;
  }
 });
});
```

```css
<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");

$tanggal2=$_POST['tanggal2'];

// Data for Titik1
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bkk_1 WHERE tanggal2='$tanggal2' LIMIT 38, 38";
$query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$rows = array();

while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $tmp;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="tanggal2" type="text" name="tanggal2" maxlength="1" size="23" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: What you are serializing? $(this).serialize();
What data you need to pass on POST?

Comment: @DiegoMachado i want to post data from `id=tanggal2` data type text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        data: { tanggal2: $('#tanggal2').val() },
        type: "POST",
        url: "../php/bkk_1/bkk_show.php",
        success: function(data) {
            var list = JSON.parse(data);
            for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
                $('#tanggal2').text((list[i]['nama']));
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it cant work. i itry to use on click and the data has been displayed.
but i need the data will be display without an event like `onclick or onchange`

Comment: By default, the input don't have any value to pass. Try to put a default value and test it again

Comment: i Have try to put a value for calling them. but still no result there

Comment: I have get the solution bro.
i put a form in there. for serialize the id. i get inspire from your code thx bro

Comment: Ok. I'm glad to help :)